# DXA 2.1 upgrade from DXA 1.7 fails

Tags: dxa, sites-9, dxa-2.1

I am working on upgrading DXA1.7 to 2.1. 400 example site publishes and retrieves fine on the browser. However we had a simple customer specific DXA1.7 module which doesn't work.

```
Sdl.Web.Common.DxaException: PCA client returned an unexpected response when retrieving page model data for page url /error-404/index.html or /error-404.html. ---> Sdl.Tridion.Api.GraphQL.Client.Exceptions.GraphQLClientException: Exception of type 'Sdl.Tridion.Api.GraphQL.Client.Exceptions.GraphQLClientException' was thrown.
GraphQLError : Exception while fetching data (/page/rawContent) : Error occurred while transforming page content at Line : 5 Column :4

   at Sdl.Tridion.Api.GraphQL.Client.GraphQLClient.HandleErrors(IGraphQLResponse response)
   at Sdl.Tridion.Api.GraphQL.Client.GraphQLClient.Execute(IGraphQLRequest graphQLrequest)
   at Sdl.Tridion.Api.Client.ApiClient.GetPageModelData(ContentNamespace ns, Int32 publicationId, String url, PageInclusion pageInclusion, ContentIncludeMode contentIncludeMode, IContextData contextData)
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.ModelService.GraphQLModelServiceProvider.GetPageModelData(String urlPath, Localization localization, Boolean addIncludes) in C:\Rancher\workspace\stash\develop\net\build_webapp\Sdl.Web.Tridion\Providers\ModelService\GraphQLModelServiceProvider.cs:line 133
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.ModelService.GraphQLModelServiceProvider.GetPageModelData(String urlPath, Localization localization, Boolean addIncludes) in C:\Rancher\workspace\stash\develop\net\build_webapp\Sdl.Web.Tridion\Providers\ModelService\GraphQLModelServiceProvider.cs:line 141
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.DefaultContentProvider.LoadPageModel(String& urlPath, Boolean addIncludes, Localization localization) in C:\Rancher\workspace\stash\develop\net\build_webapp\Sdl.Web.Tridion\Providers\DefaultContentProvider.cs:line 275
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.DefaultContentProvider.<>c__DisplayClass1_1.<GetPageModel>b__0() in C:\Rancher\workspace\stash\develop\net\build_webapp\Sdl.Web.Tridion\Providers\DefaultContentProvider.cs:line 51
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Caching.CacheProvider.GetOrAdd[T](String key, String region, Func`1 addFunction, IEnumerable`1 dependencies) in C:\Rancher\workspace\stash\develop\net\build_webapp\Sdl.Web.Tridion\Providers\Caching\CacheProvider.cs:line 64
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.DefaultContentProvider.GetPageModel(String urlPath, Localization localization, Boolean addIncludes) in C:\Rancher\workspace\stash\develop\net\build_webapp\Sdl.Web.Tridion\Providers\DefaultContentProvider.cs:line 61
   at Sdl.Web.Mvc.Controllers.PageController.NotFound()
   at Sdl.Web.Mvc.Controllers.PageController.Page(String pageUrl)
2019-06-20 02:19:03,548 [8] INFO  - Item '/system/assets/scripts/main.js' not found
2019-06-20 02:19:03,564 [8] WARN  - Errors were found during the last GraphQL request.
2019-06-20 02:19:03,564 [8] ERROR - PCA client returned an unexpected response when retrieving page model data for page url /error-404 or Exception of type 'Sdl.Tridion.Api.GraphQL.Client.Exceptions.GraphQLClientException' was thrown.
GraphQLError : Exception while fetching data (/page/rawContent) : Error occurred while transforming page content at Line : 5 Column :4
.
2019-06-20 02:19:03,564 [8] ERROR - Sdl.Web.Common.DxaException: PCA client returned an unexpected response when retrieving page model data for page url /error-404/index.html or /error-404.html. ---> Sdl.Tridion.Api.GraphQL.Client.Exceptions.GraphQLClientException: Exception of type 'Sdl.Tridion.Api.GraphQL.Client.Exceptions.GraphQLClientException' was thrown.
GraphQLError : Exception while fetching data (/page/rawContent) : Error occurred while transforming page content at Line : 5 Column :4

   at Sdl.Tridion.Api.GraphQL.Client.GraphQLClient.HandleErrors(IGraphQLResponse response)
   at Sdl.Tridion.Api.GraphQL.Client.GraphQLClient.Execute(IGraphQLRequest graphQLrequest)
   at Sdl.Tridion.Api.Client.ApiClient.GetPageModelData(ContentNamespace ns, Int32 publicationId, String url, PageInclusion pageInclusion, ContentIncludeMode contentIncludeMode, IContextData contextData)
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.ModelService.GraphQLModelServiceProvider.GetPageModelData(String urlPath, Localization localization, Boolean addIncludes) in C:\Rancher\workspace\stash\develop\net\build_webapp\Sdl.Web.Tridion\Providers\ModelService\GraphQLModelServiceProvider.cs:line 133
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.ModelService.GraphQLModelServiceProvider.GetPageModelData(String urlPath, Localization localization, Boolean addIncludes) in C:\Rancher\workspace\stash\develop\net\build_webapp\Sdl.Web.Tridion\Providers\ModelService\GraphQLModelServiceProvider.cs:line 141
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.DefaultContentProvider.LoadPageModel(String& urlPath, Boolean addIncludes, Localization localization) in C:\Rancher\workspace\stash\develop\net\build_webapp\Sdl.Web.Tridion\Providers\DefaultContentProvider.cs:line 275
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.DefaultContentProvider.<>c__DisplayClass1_1.<GetPageModel>b__0() in C:\Rancher\workspace\stash\develop\net\build_webapp\Sdl.Web.Tridion\Providers\DefaultContentProvider.cs:line 51
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Caching.CacheProvider.GetOrAdd[T](String key, String region, Func`1 addFunction, IEnumerable`1 dependencies) in C:\Rancher\workspace\stash\develop\net\build_webapp\Sdl.Web.Tridion\Providers\Caching\CacheProvider.cs:line 64
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.DefaultContentProvider.GetPageModel(String urlPath, Localization localization, Boolean addIncludes) in C:\Rancher\workspace\stash\develop\net\build_webapp\Sdl.Web.Tridion\Providers\DefaultContentProvider.cs:line 61
   at Sdl.Web.Mvc.Controllers.PageController.NotFound()
   at Sdl.Web.Mvc.Controllers.PageController.Page(String pageUrl)
Sdl.Web.Common.DxaException: PCA client returned an unexpected response when retrieving page model data for page url /error-404/index.html or /error-404.html. ---> Sdl.Tridion.Api.GraphQL.Client.Exceptions.GraphQLClientException: Exception of type 'Sdl.Tridion.Api.GraphQL.Client.Exceptions.GraphQLClientException' was thrown.
GraphQLError : Exception while fetching data (/page/rawContent) : Error occurred while transforming page content at Line : 5 Column :4

   at Sdl.Tridion.Api.GraphQL.Client.GraphQLClient.HandleErrors(IGraphQLResponse response)
   at Sdl.Tridion.Api.GraphQL.Client.GraphQLClient.Execute(IGraphQLRequest graphQLrequest)
   at Sdl.Tridion.Api.Client.ApiClient.GetPageModelData(ContentNamespace ns, Int32 publicationId, String url, PageInclusion pageInclusion, ContentIncludeMode contentIncludeMode, IContextData contextData)
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.ModelService.GraphQLModelServiceProvider.GetPageModelData(String urlPath, Localization localization, Boolean addIncludes) in C:\Rancher\workspace\stash\develop\net\build_webapp\Sdl.Web.Tridion\Providers\ModelService\GraphQLModelServiceProvider.cs:line 133
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.ModelService.GraphQLModelServiceProvider.GetPageModelData(String urlPath, Localization localization, Boolean addIncludes) in C:\Rancher\workspace\stash\develop\net\build_webapp\Sdl.Web.Tridion\Providers\ModelService\GraphQLModelServiceProvider.cs:line 141
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.DefaultContentProvider.LoadPageModel(String& urlPath, Boolean addIncludes, Localization localization) in C:\Rancher\workspace\stash\develop\net\build_webapp\Sdl.Web.Tridion\Providers\DefaultContentProvider.cs:line 275
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.DefaultContentProvider.<>c__DisplayClass1_1.<GetPageModel>b__0() in C:\Rancher\workspace\stash\develop\net\build_webapp\Sdl.Web.Tridion\Providers\DefaultContentProvider.cs:line 51
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Caching.CacheProvider.GetOrAdd[T](String key, String region, Func`1 addFunction, IEnumerable`1 dependencies) in C:\Rancher\workspace\stash\develop\net\build_webapp\Sdl.Web.Tridion\Providers\Caching\CacheProvider.cs:line 64
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.DefaultContentProvider.GetPageModel(String urlPath, Localization localization, Boolean addIncludes) in C:\Rancher\workspace\stash\develop\net\build_webapp\Sdl.Web.Tridion\Providers\DefaultContentProvider.cs:line 61
   at Sdl.Web.Mvc.Controllers.PageController.NotFound()
   at Sdl.Web.Mvc.Controllers.PageController.Page(String pageUrl)
```

Comment: Check your Content Service log file to get more insight in how it failed.

Comment: Thanks Rick I did . It gives error Caused by: com.sdl.delivery.dxa.modelservice.service.exception.DataNotFoundException: Couldn't load a page with pageId = -1, publicationId = 36, namespaceId = 1 and  I am not sure why pageid is -1. In upgrade documentation I haven't seen any changes which need to be made in the Customer modules. Other than just upgrading .net code  with latest nuget, updating webapp and installing datamodel extension. Which I did.

Comment: The error message is indeed, It's complaining about 404 for Item '/system/assets/scripts/main.js' not found, and then try to load /error-404.html page that also not exists, could you please double check those pages exist in broker db, double check published setting page is published?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed this one. So the upgrade documentation was missing a step :). When I compared New ported files in DXA Core module in CMS i found issue. It ports 2 folders under Framework/Templates. DXA.Upgrade and DXA.R2.
And in all customer modules - page and component templates refers to TBBs in DXA.Upgrade "Render Page Content" or "Render Component Content". Whereas, Core module uses TBBS in DXA.R2 with exact same name. So I just had to change reference in Customer module all Page and Component templates to point to TBBs in DXA.R2.Republish